# Disabled JTextField's border

Tags: java, swing, border, jtextfield

is there a way to disable JTextField without loosing it's border? Basically i got several text fields and some of them are enable and some are disabled. However the disabled one's don't have a border. I want all the text field look the same whether they are enabled or disabled. Is there any way how to do that?

Thanks for any answer

Comment: Are you using any special look and feel, because the default  `JTextField` doesn't disappear when disabling the control.

Answer (score 1):

In this Program You can Find the Solution

```
  import java.awt.*;  
  import java.awt.event.*;  
  import javax.swing.*;  

 public class DressingUpComponents  
{  
   JTextField disabled,  
              normal;  
  JLabel     label;  

public DressingUpComponents()  
{  
    configureDisabledTextField();  
    normal = new JTextField("hello world");  
    configureLabel();  
}  

private void configureDisabledTextField()  
{  
    disabled = new JTextField("hello world");  
    disabled.setEnabled(false);  
    Color bgColor = UIManager.getColor("TextField.background");  
    disabled.setBackground(bgColor);  
    Color fgColor = UIManager.getColor("TextField.foreground");  
    disabled.setDisabledTextColor(fgColor);  
    disabled.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());  
}  

private void configureLabel()  
{  
    label = new JLabel("hello world");  
    label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());  
    label.setOpaque(true);         // required for background colors  
    label.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("TextField.background"));  
    label.setFont(UIManager.getFont("TextField.font"));  
}  

public static void main(String[] args)  
{  
    DressingUpComponents dup = new DressingUpComponents();  
    JFrame f = new JFrame();  
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    Container cp = f.getContentPane();  
    cp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());  
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();  
    gbc.weighty = 1.0;                 // allow vertical dispersion  
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;  // single column  
    cp.add(dup.disabled, gbc);  
    cp.add(dup.normal,   gbc);  
    cp.add(dup.label,    gbc);  
    f.setSize(200,200);  
    f.setLocation(200,200);  
    f.setVisible(true);  
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `JTextField text = new JTextField;
text.setVisible(false);` I'm not sure that this will work but trying doesn't make anything lost.